# Rewriting a strictly convex quadratic equality constraint

Tags: convex-optimization

I have the following constraint
$$
x^TAx+b^Tx=c
$$
where $A$ is a positive definite matrix. Is there any way to take advantage of the strict convexity of this expression to reformulate the constraint as something simpler?

---

*Thoughts/attempt:*

I was thinking we could form $$B = A^{1/2}$$ and maybe introduce a change-of-variable as a start, but I'm not sure if this leads anywhere.

Comment: This is not a "strictly convex equality constraint." There is no such thing. It is an equality constraint involving a strictly convex function, yes. But the set it describes is non-convex, and that cannot be fixed by rewriting.

Comment: You may find it illuminating to rewrite the expression in terms of $y = A^{1/2} x$ with a symmetric positive definite root of $A$, along the lines you were thinking.  This will show you where that line of thought leads.